# Where is the sutta passage for the following citation of the description of a kalpa?

Tags: reference-request, general-buddhism

Can someone provide me a reference to the passage in the canon where the Buddha describes the length of a kalpa?

In the English Wikipedia article there is this quote which is allegedly by the Buddha:

> "Were a man to take a piece of cloth of this most delicate texture [of
> fine cotton], and therewith to touch in the slightest possible manner,
> once in a hundred years, a solid rock, free from earth, a yojana [~14
> miles] high, and as much broad, the time would come when it would be
> worn down, by this imperceptible trituration, to the size of a mung or
> undu seed. This period would be immense in its duration; but it has
> been declared by Buddha that it would not be equal to a Maha Kalpa."

I would like to find that exact passage but alas no luck. I don't know where this could be. In the wiki article the sutta nipata is mentioned but I couldn't find anything in there.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be from [SN 15.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn15.5/en/sujato). You can find similar similes in other suttas of [SN 15](https://suttacentral.net/sn15). SN is samyutta nikaya, in this case, not sutta nipata.

> Then a mendicant went up to the Buddha, bowed, sat down to one side,
> and asked him, “Sir, how long is an eon?”
>
> “Mendicant, an eon is long. It’s not easy to calculate how many years,
> how many hundreds or thousands or hundreds of thousands of years it
> lasts.”
>
> “But sir, is it possible to give a simile?”
>
> “It’s possible,” said the Buddha.
>
> “Suppose there was a huge stone mountain, a league long, a league
> wide, and a league high, with no cracks or holes, one solid mass. And
> as each century passed someone would stroke it with a fine cloth from
> Kāsī. By this means the huge stone mountain would be worn away before
> the eon comes to an end. That’s how long an eon is. And we’ve
> transmigrated through many such eons, many hundreds, many thousands,
> many hundreds of thousands.
>
> Why is that? Transmigration has no known beginning. … This is quite
> enough for you to become disillusioned, dispassionate, and freed
> regarding all conditions.”
> [SN 15.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn15.5/en/sujato)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try contemplating this while meditating :

> “Bhikkhus, there are these three feelings. What three? Pleasant
> feeling, painful feeling, neither-painful-nor-pleasant feeling. These
> are the three feelings.”
>
> Whether it be pleasant or painful Along with the
> neither-painful-nor-pleasant, Both the internal and the external,
> Whatever kind of feeling there is: Having known, “This is suffering,
> Perishable, disintegrating,” Having touched and touched them, seeing
> their fall, Thus one loses one’s passion for them